# Fixed point $\mathbb{RP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Without getting into Lefschetz theorem i can prove that any continuous map from $\mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2$ has a fixed point using the general lifting criterion.

Does the same hold for real projective line? It doesn't seem to be true as with Lefschetz we can prove it for even dimensions. But i can't think of any map that has no fixed point? Is there a trivial one?

Comment: $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is just a circle, so rotate it a little bit to get a fixed-point-free map.

Comment: Oh sure, makes sense, i was thinking of the antipodal map but it wasn't making any sense when projected

Comment: @DanielMoraes when you quotient by the antipodal map, you get a circle. Basically the point is that on $S^1$ you can rotate by $\pi/2$ and look at the map this induces on $\mathbb RP^2$. It is fixed point free

Comment: Yeah, i realized that rotating afterwards projecting makes way more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{RP}^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, so we can map $S^1$ to itself by rotating counterclockwise by $\pi/2$ radians to get a map without fixed points.